# Alternate spellings in Scrabble

Tags: scrabble, scoring

A question about alternate spellings of accepted Scrabble words: For example, "aby" (to endure or abide) can also be spelled "abye." Supposing I place the tiles for "aby" on 1 turn and then add an "e" on a subsequent turn. Do I get full credit on both turns?

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card Games Stack Exchange!  This is a nicely answerable first question, but do be sure to take our [tour] and read through the [FAQ] to better understand how Stack Exchange sites work.

Answer (score 7):

Presuming both spellings appear in the agreed authority (in case of a challenge), your example would be scored the same way as adding "s" to make a plural or present tense from a previously played word: you score full points including bonuses (doubles and triples) for all tiles played in the current turn, plus full tile value for previously played tiles you've reused (but without any doubles or triples, aside from "word" bonuses for the space the shared tile occupies, which apply to both horizontal and vertical words formed with that tile).

Comment: Both words do appear in (United States and Canada) Hasbro's [Is Your Word An Official Scrabble One?](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary)

Comment: @WeatherVane Okay, I was giving the full case -- obviously, if you do this and the alternate spelling you create *doesn't* appear in the agreed authority (say, Oxford English Dictionary, some specified edition -- or a particular edition of an official Scrabble dictionary, even), a challenge will result in loss of the turn.  But I have no idea whether obscure words like those are in any particular authority.

Comment: I was the upper, because you answered the question about scoring. Neither word appears in the online [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/) and nor do they mean anything to me. In my family, we agree to refer to the old-fashioned dictionary *book* that we like, to arbitrate.

Comment: @WeatherVane My Grandma, who taught me to play the game, always had a fairly thick Merriam-Webster on hand during her games with her best friend.  Doesn't much matter what book you like to use, as long as you agree which before the game.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: One caveat - ***do not*** under any circumstances use the 1928 (or subsequent) O.E.D. Virtually everything pronounceable is in it, so nearly all challenges automatically fail. It's use makes for a silly game.

Comment: @ForgetIwaseverhere I'll try to keep that in mind...  Not that I know many folks who'll willingly lift it...